# PHP Search Engine no results are returned even if the input matches data in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I'm trying to create a search engine for my website where users can enter keywords and the PHP script will search the 'name' and 'description' columns of my fyp_items table. So far I have managed to break down the input to an array of words and am try to execute a SELECT query on my database.

THE ISSUE is that it fails to find the items even if the keyword matches that of the data in the table. Below is my script...I hope someone can help me.

```
if(empty($_POST)=== false){
    $output = '';
    $error = '';
    $input = $_POST['search_input'];
    $i=0;
    if($input){
        $keyword = explode(" ", $input);
        require ('core/dbconnection.php');
        //If a user is logged in check if the user is Admin or Customer. 
        if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){ 
            if($admin == 1){
            }
        }else{
            //If user is not logged in search items table only.
            $search_items = "SELECT * FROM fyp_items WHERE ";
            foreach($keyword as $k){
                $k = mysql_real_escape_string($k);
                $i++;
                if($i == 1){
                    $search_items .= "name LIKE '$k' OR description LIKE '$k'";
                }else
                    $search_items .= " OR name LIKE '$k' OR description LIKE '$k'";
            }
            $item_qry = mysql_query("$search_items")or die(mysql_error());
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($item_qry);
            if($numrows > 0){
                $output = 'found it';
            }else
                $error = '<p class="pageerror">Sorry, what you were looking for was not found.</p>';
        }
    }else
        $error = '<p class="pageerror">Please enter your search terms.</p>';
```

I have tested the post by echoing the output and I have also echoed the `$search_items` variable to get this...
http://awesomescreenshot.com/05c2fwytac

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: try using `LIKE '%word%'` using wilcard

Comment: Yes, %word% is what I use with MySQLi and it worked for me. Try it.

Comment: You might consider using MySQL natural language search for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building an incorrect query string, that'll be something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE 'foo' OR description LIKE 'foo'
```

a `LIKE` comparison without wilcards is pointless. You've functionally got the equivalent of

```
SELECT ... WHERE name='foo' OR description='foo'
```

The wildcards allow substring matching in the fields:

```
SELECT ... WHERE name='%foo%' OR description = '%foo%'
```

so the word `foo` can appear ANYWHERE in the field and match. Right now your query will only match if `foo` is the ONLY thing in either field.

And these sorts of queries are highly inefficient, especially as the number of search terms climbs. You should be suing a `fulltext` search: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html